# Grub Install x86_64-efi doesn't exist - LFS

Tags: grub2, lfs

I've been following along with the stable systemd Linux from Scratch and have got to the final chapter where we configure grub to make the system bootable.

So I've run `grub-install /dev/sda1` (`/dev/sda1` is my `/boot` partition) and I get this error:

```
grub-install: error: /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/modinfo.sh doesn't exist. Please specify --target or --directory.
```

Looking in `/usr/lib/grub/` I do, in-fact, only have an `i386-pc` entry.

So I've tried rerunning the command with that as a target and get a different error:

```
(lfs chroot) root:/boot# grub-install /dev/sda1 --target i386-pc
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: File system `fat' doesn't support embedding.
grub-install: error: embedding is not possible, but this is required for cross-disk install.
```

Usually, I use systemd-boot, but that's not included with the version of systemd that's been installed in this LFS system and I don't fancy upgrading it, so I'd quite like to make grub work.

What's going on here? How can I start fixing this?

Comment: Are you sure you do not have a 64 bit system with UEFI. If you used SystemD to boot, that is normally UEFI. Old (very old) BIOS install to newer gpt requires a bios_grub partition or grub attempts embedding which is not recommended and may not work. Does LFS have UEFI boot, not familiar with it.

Comment: @oldfred - Yeah I am booted with EFI on my host. Can't grub handle uefi?

Comment: Grub has two versions for PCs (other versions also) one grub-efi-amd64 for UEFI boot and grub-pc for BIOS boot.How you boot install or boot repair media typically is the version that is installed.

Comment: Have not used LFS, but found this: https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/grub-setup.html

Answer (score 1):

I read the section “Using GRUB to Set Up the Boot Process” in scratch. The note on the bottom said “ If your system has UEFI support and you wish to boot LFS with UEFI, you should skip the instructions in this page but still learn the syntax of grub.cfg and the method to specify a partition in the file from this page, and configure GRUB with UEFI support using the instructions provided in the BLFS page.”

https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter10/grub.html

So as you said you are booted with UEFI, you should follow the above note.

Comment: I had totally missed that note... Thanks!